# What happens if emails are sent to addresses at example domains via AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Though I realize I could set up a blacklist in my server-side code and avoid sending emails to [RFC 2606 example domains](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606), let's set that aside.

What happens if I send email to addresses such as `test@example.com` via SES?

There are no MX records for those domains, so the email will never actually get to a destination, but, assuming I send to SES via SMTP:

- Will it count towards my sending total, for billing purposes?
- Will it count as bounced or anything like that which might negatively affect me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it count towards my sending total, for billing purposes?

Yes.

SES charges per recipient attempted, not per message delivered.

> Will it count as bounced or anything like that which might negatively affect me?

Yes.

> Remember that excessive bounces, complaints, and attempts to send low-quality email constitute abuse and put your AWS account at risk of termination.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/deliverability-and-ses.html

SES expects you to manage the addresses you send to, to monitor your bounce (meaning anything undeliverable) and complaint feedback, to remove bouncing addresses from your list.

There's also a global suppression list, populated from prior failed deliveries (hard bounces) across all customers.  If you send to one of those addresses, they don't tie up resources trying to deliver it, but it still counts as a bounce, and it's still billed.

> Emails to addresses on the suppression list will be billed according to the normal Amazon SES pricing plan, except for the data transfer out bandwidth for which you are exempt for the suppressed destinations. This precisely matches the current behavior in the case where emails are sent to invalid addresses not known to have bounced before.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/goodbye-blacklist-introducing-the-suppression-list/

However... there's an official set of test addresses provided by the [mailbox simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html) for success as well as multiple types of bounces.  It seems like you *could* use these as your dummy addresses, if you really wanted to.  These don't count against you as bounces, but according to the documentation, they are still billed.

You might also find the [Enforcement FAQ](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/e-faq.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll leave my test accounts' addresses at example.com, but blacklist them for email sending purposes. I mainly wondered if AWS might have a special case in place for those domains.